# How can I select a specific range in VB.net

Tags: excel, vb.net, vsto, office-addins, excel-addins

I can get either the name of a Named range, or the refersTo address in a variable called rngName.

How can I actually select that range on the active workbook using VB.net in a Visual Studio Add-in?

If the address has sheet name inside, 'sheetName!C1' do I need to select the sheet separately before the range?

Answer (score 0):

For example, to select cell D5 on the active worksheet, you can use either of the following examples:

```
ActiveSheet.Cells(5, 4).Select
-or-
ActiveSheet.Range("D5").Select
```

If you need to select a named range you can use the following code:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("RangeName").Select
```

Read more about all possible ways in the [How to select cells/ranges by using Visual Basic procedures in Excel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/troubleshoot/office-developer/select-cells-rangs-with-visual-basic) article.

> If the address has sheet name inside, 'sheetName!C1' do I need to select the sheet separately before the range?

Most probably you need to activate the sheet first. For example:

```
Workbooks("BOOK2.XLS").Sheets("Sheet2").Activate
Range("Test").Select
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, but i was i'm building an Addin in Visual Studio, using VB.net. The commands you mentioned work on Excel with VBA. The commands i'm looking for will look something like "Dim WB As Excel.Workbook = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook", i just can't seem to find the code to actually do the select

Comment: You are right you need to use the Excel `Application` instance to call this shorthand properties available in VBA. Note, the Excel object model is the same for all kind of applications - no matter whether it is VBA or VB.NET.